# Why does the capacitor part of the electret mic have very high impedance and why is a FET used to solve the problem?

Tags: impedance-matching

As far as I understand a FET is used for impedance conversion of the capacitor part of the electret microphone. I dont understand the meaning of that.

The reason is given that the capacitor itself has very high impedance(I guess output impedance).

Can you explain why the capacitor itself has a very high impedance and why is that a problem? And how does the FET makes it useful? An answer with simple circuit examples help.

Comment: For small capacitances, a LARGE value of resistor is needed to ensure good bass response (those low frequencies in the music). The FET provides that large value of resistor. Regarding the capacitor, the impedance depends on both the frequency and the value of capacitance. At present I'm assisting in using some piezo-electric sensors with 22,000pF self-capacitance.  Given 1uF at 1MegaHertz has -j0.16 ohms impedance, and 1uF at 1Hertz has -j 160,000 ohms impedance, then 0.22uF (that same 22,000pF) at 1 Hertz has 160,000 * (1/0.22) or 160K * 45 or 8,000,000 ohms impedance. A HPF sets freq 3dB.

Comment: High impedance means the low current capability. The small electret mic capacitor is not able to provide any current. So we need an amplifier. So we add a JFET common-source amplifier to the mic. And the JFET is a Voltage-driven amplifier.

Comment: @G36 Can you show this with a circuit example why a capacitor has large output impedance I mean?

Answer (score -1):

Please refer to chapter 2 of [this](http://www.ti.com/lit/ug/tidu765/tidu765.pdf) reference design description from TI. (There is everything you want to know.)